# Delcare and access multidimensional array in swift

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array

I would like to declare an array which should look like this:

```
myArray
  ->Car (Array)
    - Ford
    - Audi
    - ...
  ->Color (Array)
    - Red
    - Green
    - ...
  ->Wheels (Simple String, eg "4")
  ->Roof (Simple String, eg, "NO")
```

Im stuck in space to delare and access this type of array. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2):

I think creating custom objects (with classes or structs) would be better suited for you, like this for example:

```
class Car {

    var brand: String?
    var color: String?
    var wheels: Int?

    init(brand: String, color: String, wheels: Int = 4) {
        self.brand = brand
        self.color = color
        self.wheels = wheels
    }

}

let myAudi = Car(brand: "Audi", color: "red")
let myFord = Car(brand: "Ford", color: "green", wheels: 3)

var myCars = [Car]()

myCars.append(myAudi)
myCars.append(myFord)

for aCar in myCars {
    println("My \(aCar.brand!) is \(aCar.color!) and has \(aCar.wheels!) wheels.")
}
```

Result:

> My Audi is red and has 4 wheels.
>   My Ford is green and has 3 wheels.

*Note: have a look at [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html), it will help.*

Answer (score 0):

you can create an array with each elements as an array. For example

```
var tempArr : [[String]] = [["Ford","Audi"],["Red","Green"],["4"],["NO"]]
```

based on your question i guess you need a dictionary and not an array

```
var tempDict : [String : [String]] = ["Car" : ["Ford","Audi"],.....]
```